# c# windows service in windows 7 The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

Tags: c#

I am  runing c# windows service in windows 7.i am getting this error.

> {System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some
>   or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
>   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source,
>   String machineName, Boolean readOnly)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String
>   machineName)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.VerifyAndCreateSource(String sourceName,
>   String currentMachineName)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message,
>   EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
>   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String source, String
>   message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[]
>   rawData)    at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String source,
>   String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID)    at
>   eFpdaDMSservice.Utils.GetRegValue(RegistryKey regKey, String
>   strSubKey, String strName, String strDefault)

I have given permissions in the registry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog

it is breaking at this point

```
strTempDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp");
            **strLogDir = Utils.GetRegValue(Registry.LocalMachine,REG_KEY,"logdir",strTempDir);**
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What account are you running the service under ? You can try to change the Account to LocalSystem and see if it fixes your problem.

[image]